# JS создать блок ниже или выше скрипта

Tags: javascript

Создаю скрипт вывода баннера. Есть блок с уникальным ID в него выводится баннер. Как сделать, чтобы если блок не существует создать его в том же месте где выводится  скрипт? document.write не помогает, так как скрипт проверяет наличие блока после загрузки DOM.

Сейчас реализовал так. Хоть и работает это, но мне кажется сделал коряво (=

```html
<script>
var div=document.getElementById("My_ID");
if(!div){document.write('<div id="My_ID"></div>');}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
div=document.getElementById("My_ID");
//Здесь делаю действия с блоком
div.innerHTML='Вставляем баннер';
});
</script>
```

Comment: Это не только "коряво", но и неправильно. Вам же показали, как надо.

Comment: Как показали не работает правильно. ИД присваивать скрипту нежелательно. Да и все варианты не выводили блок в нужном месте - т.е. сразу ниже или выше скрипта. Возможно, это связано с тем, что таких скриптов может быть несколько на странице.

Comment: Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе код из второго фрагмента в моем ответе.

Comment: Еще раз попробовал. Работает неправильно. Если один вызов скрипта - все работает. А если несколько - все баннеры лепятся в одну кучу у последнего скрипта. А должно быть каждый на своем месте.

Comment: Все верно. Извиняюсь. Ошибку сделал, что при копировании не включал что выполнение внутри функции. Действительно все работает. Попутно можете объяснить разницу? Я использовал document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){... а вы window.addEventListener("load", function() {... В чем разница?

Comment: Это различие как раз непринципиально. Я считаю неправильным поиск элемента (который может находиться ниже на странице) в момент загрузки скрипта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div>before</div>
<script id="myScript">
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log("loaded");
    var div = document.getElementById("Мой_ID");
    if (!div) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = "Мой_ID";
      div.textContent = "dynamic";
      // Вставляем сразу ниже или выше этого скрипта
      var thisScript = document.getElementById("myScript");
      thisScript.parentNode.insertBefore(div, thisScript);
    }
  });
  console.log("loading");
</script>
<div>after</div>
```

Можно обойтись без `id` в тэге скрипта:

```html
<div>before</div>
<script>
(function() {
  var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script");
  var thisScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log("loaded");
    var div = document.getElementById("Мой_ID");
    if (!div) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = "Мой_ID";
      div.textContent = "dynamic";
      // Вставляем сразу ниже или выше этого скрипта
      thisScript.parentNode.insertBefore(div, thisScript);
    }
  });
  console.log("loading");
})();
</script>
<div>after</div>

<div>before1</div>
<script>
(function() {
  var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script");
  var thisScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log("loaded1");
    var div = document.getElementById("Мой_ID1");
    if (!div) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = "Мой_ID1";
      div.textContent = "dynamic1";
      // Вставляем сразу ниже или выше этого скрипта
      thisScript.parentNode.insertBefore(div, thisScript);
    }
  });
  console.log("loading1");
})();
</script>
<div>after1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я верно Вас понял, то Вот так:

```css
#ddd{
  border:solid
}
```

```html
<script>
var div=document.getElementById("ddd");
if(!div){
  var div=document.createElement("div");
  div.id="ddd";
  document.body.append(div)
}
</script>

<script>
var div=document.getElementById("ddd");
if(!div){
  var div=document.createElement("div");
  div.id="ddd";
  document.body.append(div)
}
</script>
```

Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]